# How to call a shared method from a react app and a web worker

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, web-worker

How can I reference a utility class in both a React app and a web worker?

Here's a bare-bones **create-react-app** that demonstrates my core issue. The web worker code itself works fine, it just doesn't have access to the Util class.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Util from './Util.js'
import worker from './Util.worker.js';
import WebWorker from './WebWorker.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.util = new Util();
        this.state = { something: "" };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.worker = new WebWorker(worker);
        this.worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
            this.setState({ something: e.data })
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p onClick={e => this.randomHandler()}>{this.util.DoSomething("hello")}</p>
                <p>{this.state.something}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    randomHandler() {
        console.log("err")
        this.worker.postMessage(["cool"]);
    }
}
```

Util.js

```
export default class Util {
    DoSomething(x) {
        return this.AnotherMethod(x) + "!";
    }
    AnotherMethod(x) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

WebWorker.js

```
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['(' + code + ')()']);
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}
```

Util.worker.js

```
export default () => {
    self.addEventListener('message', function(e) { // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals
        postMessage("How do I call Util.DoSomething() here?");
    }, false);
}
```

Here's what I want to be able to do.

```
var util = new Util();
postMessage(util.DoSomething(e.data));
```

Typically a web worker is instantiated on a file path, but that doesn't play well with React due to the way the app is compiled. That's why several sources recommended serializing the method and dynamically creating the worker from that (which is what I'm doing).

I've tried passing both serialized instances of the class and the class itself to the worker, but that didn't work out (and it feels hackish).

I've also tried importing the Util class in the web worker, but I just get reference errors because the WebWorker class doesn't process the import.

Could someone with experience in this area point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What specifically stops you from compiling a new bundle for the worker? You say it doesn't play well, but really that's the right way.

Comment: @loganfsmyth When I initially went down that path I couldn't find a way to reference the compiled module without knowing it's location after compilation. Several places proposed the dynamic object URL as a solution to that problem. I'm hoping the answer isn't just a complicated build pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer was to eject the configs from Create React App. Once [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3934) is merged we shouldn't need to do that.

Run these commands. Note that the eject command is irreversible.

```
npm run eject
npm install thread-loader
npm install worker-loader
```

Add this to the webpack.config (both dev and prod) in the module>rules>oneOf section.

```
{
  test: /\.worker\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
  include: paths.appSrc,
  use: [
    require.resolve('worker-loader'),
    // This loader parallelizes code compilation, it is optional but
    // improves compile time on larger projects
    require.resolve('thread-loader'),
    {
      loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
      options: {
        // @remove-on-eject-begin
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
        // @remove-on-eject-end
        // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
        // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
        // directory for faster rebuilds.
        cacheDirectory: true,
        highlightCode: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Then Util.worker.js becomes this:

```
import Util from './Util.js'

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var util = new Util();
    self.postMessage(util.DoSomething(e.data)); 
}, false);
```

And App.js becomes this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Util from './Util.js'
import Worker from './Util.worker.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.util = new Util();
        this.state = { something: "" };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.worker = new Worker();
        this.worker.onmessage = e => {
            console.warn(e.data);
            this.setState({ something: e.data });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p onClick={e => this.randomHandler()}>{this.util.DoSomething("hello")}</p>
                <p>{this.state.something}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    randomHandler() {
        console.log("err")
        this.worker.postMessage("cool");
    }
}
```